# Link index is doubled as the start button is clicked multiple times

Tags: javascript

I am learning Vanilla Javascript and my apologies if this question is asked before.

I have random numbers (example 1 - 10) displayed in a list of links.

In my js script, the links are stored as an array in a variable using querySelectorAll from the class name.

When a start button is clicked which enables a click event on the links, I want to get the index of the link that is clicked or selected. I am using a forEach loop to select the link in the array by the help of event listener in the forEach loop.

However, I see the event listener firing multiple times as the start button is clicked multiple times.

What I want is to either reset and reenable the click event every time the start button is clicked or always get one click event per link regardless of the start button being clicked more than once.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Here is my code:

```js
function handleSelection() {
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".game-list-items");

  links.forEach(function (link) {
  
    function getIndex(l) {
      l.preventDefault();
      console.log("Index of link selected");
    }

    link.addEventListener("click", getIndex);
  });
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please can you direct me to the answer? I searched here before posting and none of the answers resolved my issue.